# Download a file from a linux system to your home computer

Tags: linux

I am ssh logged into a system. It is a remote system I am not in control of, but it has a directory with data I can work with. How do I download datasets from that linux system to my home computer?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general Linux usage issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: You can use any scp (secure copy) client to copy from the remote system to your local system (assuming the remote system is configured to permit such remote copying).

Comment: I don't understand the syntax though. I tried using scp but it says it cannot recognize my local system, or home computer.

Comment: Well, if you have a specific problem like that then you should provide the exact details. Include the exact commands and resulting logs. Anyway, as I said, this question does not belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand but I just want to download it do my desktop, that's it.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to ask the question at the right place and you need to provide the details of what you tried and how it failed. That's it.

Comment: I tried the following:
scp /****/data/data.txt C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop

Comment: Not sure how much clearer it has to be said - post your question over at [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and include the **exact** command and full error msgs. If you want help then please take time to follow the posting guidelines and provide the info others need to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use SCP to securely transfer files between two Unix computers.

- scp command usage :
  **scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2**
- Example:

To copy a file called rebels.txt from your home directory on empire.gov to a directory called revenge in your account on the computer deathstar.com, enter:
**scp ~/rebels.txt dvader@deathstar.com:~/revenge**

A detailed example can be found here:[link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye#:%7E:text=In%20Unix%2C%20you%20can%20use,password%20or%20passphrase%20for%20authentication.)

Comment: this is realy close, but i'm tying to get the txt file to my home desktop.

Comment: Are you using Windows os?